# How to skip second activity after first run forever?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, timer

I am working on one app which contain `SplashScreen.java` my first activity. After that its show `LoginActivity.java` for login. And my `LoginActivity.java` class eventually start `SplashActivity.java`. I want after login first time everytime i start my app `SplashScreen.java` calls `SplashActivity.java` instead of `LoginActivity.java`. For this i made some changes in my `SplashScreen.java` class but its not working fine.

SplashScreen.java Class-

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity 
{
    private long splashDelay = 5000; //5 seconds
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);
        SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("ActivityPREF", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        if(pref.getBoolean("activity_executed", false))
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SplashActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        } 
        else 
        {
            Editor ed = pref.edit();
            ed.putBoolean("activity_executed", true);
            ed.commit();
        }
        TimerTask task = new TimerTask()
        {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                finish();
                Intent mainIntent = new Intent().setClass(SplashScreen.this, LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(mainIntent);
            }

        };

        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(task, splashDelay);
    }
}
```

Anyone else help me. Now the only problem after first run. App start from `SplashActivity` instead of starting from `SplashScreen`.

Comment: What do you mean by `its not working fine.`

Comment: @geet after SplashActivity i have QuestionActivity. In SplashActivity i have exit button which transfer control to back Splashactivity. And exit button in Splash Activity transfer control to back exit button in QuestionActivity i.e recursive manner.

Comment: @geet i know its littlt confusing please let me know if you unable to understand.

Comment: @geet i solved recursive problem. But next time i start app still showing LoginActivity.

Comment: Try to put your TimerTask in else.

Comment: @geet is it possible to chat with you in chat room?

Comment: @geet what you suggested me working. i have little part remaining please help me in this too. sorry if not want to chat in room.

Comment: Its ok. you can check my answer. let me know if any error occurs

Comment: @geet its working but next time when i start app its always start from SplashActivity instead of starting from SplashScreen and then to go on SplashActivity.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38607/discussion-between-john-r-and-geet)

Comment: @geet one thing i forget to ask you know punjabi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@John check and just refer this working code, i hope,it help u,

```
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    pref = getSharedPreferences("ActivityPREF", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Log.v("","onCreate is calling");
    if(pref.getBoolean("activity_executed", false))
    {
         Log.v("","Before if called");
        setContentView(R.layout.menu_frame);
         Log.v("","after if called");
         new Handler().postDelayed(csRunnable1, 3000);

    } 
    else 
    {
       new Handler().postDelayed(csRunnable2, 3000);  
        Editor ed = pref.edit();
        ed.putBoolean("activity_executed", true);
        ed.commit();

    }


}
Runnable csRunnable1=new Runnable() 
{       
    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
         Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, SplashActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();

    }
};
Runnable csRunnable2=new Runnable() 
 {      
    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
         Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();

    }
};
```

Comment: after so many changes your answer is working completely fine. need your one more little help. when you back text me here. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
     @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);
            SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("ActivityPREF",  Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            Editor ed = pref.edit();
     Boolean Exist=pref.getBoolean("activity_executed", false);// Check is user logged in or not
            if(Exist)// if allready logged in then forward it to Splash Activity
            {

                Intent intent = new Intent(this, SplashActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            } 
            else // Not logged in
            {

               Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 2000L);
             }
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            new AsyncParsing().execute();

        }
    };

    private class AsyncParsing extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Log.d("Splash Activity", "In pre execute");

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            Log.d("Splash Activity", "In do in backgriund ");


            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            Log.d("Splash Activity", "In post execute");
                   Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                }
           }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

> Step 1 : Declare this in ur login class

```
SharedPreferences pref;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
```

> Step 2 :Declare In onCrete method

```
pref = getSharedPreferences("login", MODE_PRIVATE);
editor = pref.edit();
```

> Step 3 : OnClick of submit button in login page paste the lines below
>   :

```
String check=pref.getString("selected", "nil")
if(check.equals("TRUE"))
{
Intent intent=new Intent(this,splash.class);
startActivity(intent);
}
```

> Step 4: put this where u r getting the success message when user credentails and db credentials matches.

```
editor.putString("selected", "TRUE");
editor.commit();
```

Comment: Please make this changes also with @patrioit answer. then your app perfect. thank you for this code Monica the great.

Comment: the great check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182761/finish-old-activity-and-start-a-new-one-or-vice-versa

Answer (score 0):

I would think you have a logic problem there. Should be if not executed, run it and mark as executed.

```
if(!pref.getBoolean("activity_executed", false)) {
    Editor ed = pref.edit();
    ed.putBoolean("activity_executed", true);
    ed.commit();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SplashActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

Comment: not working same recursive problem read comments below question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that calling finish does not stop the rest of onCreate from being executed. You need to put a return statement after:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SplashActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this
  @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);
        SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("ActivityPREF", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        if(pref.getBoolean("activity_executed", false))
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SplashActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
        else
        {
            Editor ed = pref.edit();
            ed.putBoolean("activity_executed", true);
            ed.commit();
            Timer timer = new Timer();
            TimerTask task = new TimerTask()
            {

                @Override
                public void run() { 
                    timer.cancel();
                    Intent mainIntent = new Intent().setClass(SplashScreen.this, LoginActivity.class);
                    startActivity(mainIntent);
                    finish();
                }

            };

            timer.schedule(task, splashDelay);
        }

    }
```

Comment: i've tried your code. but next time my app start its start from SplashActicity not from SplashScreen.

Answer (score 0):

You missing I hope It will solve your problem

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity 
{private long splashDelay = 5000; // 5 seconds

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            finish();
            Intent mainIntent = new Intent().setClass(Test.this,
                    LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(mainIntent);
        }

    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);
        SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("ActivityPREF",
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        if (pref.getBoolean("activity_executed", false)) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SplashActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        } else {

            Editor ed = pref.edit();
            ed.putBoolean("activity_executed", true);
            ed.commit();



            Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(task, splashDelay);




        }

    }
}
```

Comment: i've tried your code. but next time my app start its start from SplashActicity not from SplashScreen