# On calling finish() before startActivity method, Activity transition takes place

Tags: android, android-activity

In my android application i made the mistake of calling startActivity method after finish() but still I was able to move to the next activity. I want to know how this happened shouldn't the activity be destroyed before the startActivity is executed 
Here is a Sample Code

```
    Intent N=new Intent(A.this,B.class);
    finish();
    startActivity(N);
```

I am able to move to Activity B without any problem and also Activity A is destroyed

Comment: Check this thread - http://stackoverflow.com/a/4185897/7235049

Comment: Also read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23778611/3921977) answer for additional info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it depends from where you called finish()

finish() in **onCreate()** will call onDestroy()

finish() in **onStart()** will call onCreate(), onStart(), onStop(), onDestroy()

finish() in **onResume()** will call onCreate(), onStart(), onResume(), onPause(), onStop(), onDestroy()

you can take a look on the Android life cycle :

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe `finish()` has the same effects as a return (otherwise we would get the `unreachable statement` error), so the rest of the flow still gets called.

[More info.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8282569/oncreate-flow-continues-after-finish)