# Android app crashes with a flashing screen

Tags: android, xml, firebase

I am new to android development am learning to do authentication with firebase, i created three activity MainActivity, LoginActivity, and FeedActivity. what's happening is i am loading the app on my Xiaomi redmi phone with android 7.1.1 loaded, it opens up and looks to work fine, but am trying to signup with a new account, instead of taking me to the FeedActivity, it makes the whole screen flash in white, everything stops working, the only way to stop it is kill the application and go to home screen.

**MainActivity**

```
package com.example.ahmed.myapplication;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private Button buttonRegister;
    private EditText editTextEmail;
    private EditText editTextPassword;
    private TextView textViewLogin;

    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()!= null){
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FeedActivity.class));
        }
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

        buttonRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRegister);

        editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
        editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);

        textViewLogin = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewLogin);

        buttonRegister.setOnClickListener(this);
        textViewLogin.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private void registerUser() {
        String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
        String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
            //email is empty
            Toast.makeText(this, "Opps! Please Enter Email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //stop the function

            return;
        }

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
            //password is empty
            Toast.makeText(this, "Opps! Please Enter Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //stop the function

            return;
        }

        progressDialog.setMessage("Getting you in...");
        progressDialog.show();

        firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
                                finish();
                                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FeedActivity.class));

                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Welcome, to My App.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Opps, Something went wrong! Try Again!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        progressDialog.dismiss();

                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view == buttonRegister) {
            registerUser();
        }

        if (view == textViewLogin) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));
        }

    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        tools:context="com.example.ahmed.myapplication.MainActivity">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Sign Up and Inspire!"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large" />



        <EditText
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:hint="Enter Your Email"
            android:id="@+id/editTextEmail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


        <EditText
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:hint="Enter Your Password"
            android:id="@+id/editTextPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:id="@+id/buttonRegister"
            android:text="Sign Up"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:text="Already On signed up? Sign In Here"
            android:id="@+id/textViewLogin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

**LoginActivity**

```
package com.example.ahmed.myapplication;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private Button buttonLogin;
    private EditText editTextEmail;
    private EditText editTextPassword;
    private TextView textViewSignup;

    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);


        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()!= null){
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FeedActivity.class));
        }
        editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
        editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
        buttonLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLogin);
        textViewSignup = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewSignup);

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);


        buttonLogin.setOnClickListener(this);
        textViewSignup.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    private void userLogin() {
        String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
        String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
            //email is empty
            Toast.makeText(this, "Opps! Please Enter Email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //stop the function

            return;
        }

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
            //password is empty
            Toast.makeText(this, "Opps! Please Enter Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //stop the function

            return;
        }

        progressDialog.setMessage("Finding Your Account...");
        progressDialog.show();

        firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        if (task.isSuccessful()){
                            finish();
                            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FeedActivity.class));
                        }

                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        if (view == buttonLogin){
            userLogin();
        }

        if (view == textViewSignup){
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
        }
    }
}
```

**activity_login.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.ahmed.myapplication.LoginActivity">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="79dp">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Welcome Back Buddy!"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large" />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextEmail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:hint="Enter Your Email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:hint="Enter Your Password"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonLogin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:text="Log In" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewSignup"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New To My App? Sign Up Now"
            android:textAlignment="center" />


    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**FeedActivity**

```
package com.example.ahmed.myapplication;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

public class FeedActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private TextView textViewUserEmail;
    private Button buttonLogout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_feed);


        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()!= null){
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class));
        }

        FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

        textViewUserEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewUserEmail);
        textViewUserEmail.setText("Welcome friend"+user.getEmail());
        buttonLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLogout);

        buttonLogout.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        if (view == buttonLogout){
            firebaseAuth.signOut();
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help in advance

**activity_feed.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.ahmed.myapplication.FeedActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewUserEmail"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Ander Agaya te!"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Sign Out"
            android:id="@+id/buttonLogout"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: post your error log

Comment: why are you calling finish() before startActivity() in your MainActivity, FeedActivity and LoginActivity ?

Comment: post your error...

Comment: you should call finish() after starting your new activity.

Comment: white screen may be the finish calling first
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182761/finish-old-activity-and-start-a-new-one-or-vice-versa

Answer (score 0):

Change this -:

```
if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
                                finish();
                                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FeedActivity.class));

                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Welcome, to My App.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Opps, Something went wrong! Try Again!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
```

To-:

```
if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

                                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FeedActivity.class));

finish();

                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Welcome, to My App.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Opps, Something went wrong! Try Again!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
```

Call finish after that line...

Comment: hey @Shivam Oberoi i did this, and the flashing is gone but my app get freezes, without even going to the FeedActivity, i tried stopping the app and opening it again but it freezes, and there is nothing in the logs

Answer (score 0):

make change in if condition in FeedActivity.class

```
 if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()!= null){
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class));
        }
```

to

```
 if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()= null){

            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class));
 finish();
            }
```

Comment: check my if condition

Comment: Shivam repeated your answer @LUCKY

Comment: hey @Vinesh Chauhan i tried this, and the flashing is gone but my app get freezes, without even going to the FeedActivity, i tried stopping the app and opening it again but it freezes, and there is nothing in the logs – Noor Ali Khan just now   edit

Comment: you are answering same to two different solution so how we can get what solution worked for you

Comment: your reply same as Shivam

Comment: because may be none of the two solutions worked for me, i got the same issue with both the solutions